# Trying to parse the div, but I get an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from texttable import Texttable

url = "https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/"
site = requests.get(url) #send a request to the site

table = Texttable() #create a table
table.set_chars(['-', '|', '+', '='])
table.header(['Titel','Company','Location'])
table.set_cols_dtype(['t','i','a'])
table.set_cols_align(["c", "c", "c"])
table.set_cols_valign(["m", "m", "m"])
table.set_cols_width([20,20,20])
table.set_deco(Texttable.BORDER|Texttable.HEADER |Texttable.HLINES| Texttable.VLINES)


with open('Shore.txt', 'w') as f: #create a file
    pass

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")
job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="card-content") #find all div with class "card-content"



for job_element in job_elements:
    title_element = job_element.find("h2", class_="title") #get the different elements from divs with class "card-content"
    company_element = job_element.find("h3", class_="company") #get the different elements from divs with class "card-content"
    location_element = job_element.find("p", class_="location") #get the different elements from divs with class "card-content"
    item_element = job_element.find("a", class_="card-footer-item") #get the link with divs from class "card-content"
    
    item_site = requests.get(item_element["href"]) #send a request to the site from link
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(item_site.content, "html.parser")
    results_site = item_soup.find(id="ResultsContainer") 
    item_element_elements = results_site.find("div", class_="content")
    item_element_element = item_element_elements.find("p", class_=False) #get the text without class
    
    print(title_element.text.strip()) #get it all data received into the console
    print(company_element.text.strip()) #get all data received into the console
    print(location_element.text.strip()) #get all data received into the console
    print(item_element_element.text.strip()) # get all data received into the console
    table.add_row([title_element.text.strip(),company_element.text.strip(),location_element.text.strip()]) #add rows in corrects rows "add_rows"
    with open('Shore.txt', 'w') as f: #enter all data received into a table file
        f.write(table.draw())
        f.write(str(len(job_elements)))
        f.close
print(len(job_elements)) #get the number of elements with the class
```

Error:

```
line 38, in <module>
    item_element_elements = results_site.find("div", class_="content")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Trying to parse the div:

```
item_element_elements = results_site.find("div", class_="content")
item_element_element = item_element_elements.find("p", class_=False)
```

But I get an error. `Can't find the "find" attribute`. I was able to parse all the other elements. No idea how to fix this.

Comment: the problem is in this line: `results_site = item_soup.find(id="ResultsContainer") ` it finds nothing with this id, hence `result_site` is `None`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select your elements more specific - Issue here is that you select the first link and not that one that is leading to the details:

```
item_element = job_element.select_one("a.card-footer-item[href*='fake-jobs/jobs']")
```

or

```
item_element = job_element.find_all("a", class_="card-footer-item")[-1]
```

*You could do it also with `.find()` but may checkout the [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
url = "https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

for job_element in soup.select('#ResultsContainer .card-content')[:1]:
    #...
    item_element = job_element.select_one("a.card-footer-item[href*='fake-jobs/jobs']") #get the link with divs from class "card-content"

    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(item_element.get("href")).text)
    item_element_element = item_soup.select_one("div.content p").text #get the text without class
    print(item_element_element)
```